# Is it possible to scrape HTML from Inspect Element in Python?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site that attempts to block scraping. Viewing the source code through Chrome, or requests, or requests_html results it not showing the correct source code.

Here is an example:

```python
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

content = session.get('website')

content.html.render()

print(content.html.html)
```

It gives this page:
It looks like JavaScript is disabled or not supported by your browser.

Even though Javascript is enabled. Same thing happens on an actual browser.

However, on my actual browser, when I go to inspect element, I can see the source code just fine. Is there a way to extract the HTML source from inspect element?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, actually, https://www.bustabit.com/play

It's a gambling site, and I want to scrape the numbers for ~1 month just out of curiosity to see what the odds are.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is that it's a page which is rendered by the Javascript on the front-end. In this case, you would require a javasacript enabled browser-engine and then you can easily read the HTML source.

Here's a working code of how I would do it (using selenium):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  

chrome_options = Options()  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options) 

# Ensure that the full URL path is given
URL = 'https://proper_url'

# The following step will launch a browser.
driver.get(URL)

# Now you can easily read the source HTML
HTML = driver.page_source
```

You will have to figure out the details of installing and setting up Selenium and the webdriver. [Here's](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) a good place to start.

Comment: Hello, this doesn't work. Viewing the source code through my actual browser doesn't work either, only inspect element.